# Hiding Button as a function of position with InfiniteViewPager

Tags: java, android, xml, android-viewpager

Just in case somebody is familiar with InfiniteViewPager. I've also started an Issue there, but I was hoping perhaps somebody here might have some insight.

InfiniteViewPager: https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager.

The following code sets up my InfiniteViewPager and hides a button depending on the position of the pager. It works, as in the button starts GONE, and appears when you swipe to a new position, but as you swipe back to "position 0" the button reappears. I believe this is because when I swipe back, the position is no longer really "position 0". I get the following in my logcat:

```
11-23 23:29:49.694 25109-25109/com.app.store D/InfinitePagerAdapter﹕ instantiateItem: real position: 3301
11-23 23:29:49.694 25109-25109/com.app.store D/InfinitePagerAdapter﹕ instantiateItem: virtual position: 1
```

This is the code for initiating my pager and the OnPageChangeListener.

```
private void init(Context context) {
    View view = inflate(context, R.layout.listview_item, this);
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter;
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(context);

    PagerAdapter wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);

    //Hide the button unless showing image
    final Button selectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectButton);
    selectButton .setVisibility(GONE);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
             if(position==0)
                selectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             else
                selectButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Basically, I hide the button on "position 0" and show it for every other position using OnPageChangeListener. However, when I return to "position 0", it doesn't recognize "position 0" as "position 0", so it's not hiding the button.

**Edit: I've included my XML**

```
<com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop">

            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/custom_viewpagertitlestrip"
                android:layout_gravity="top" />

        </com.antonyt.infiniteviewpager.InfiniteViewPager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
if(position % size == 0)
      selectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
      selectButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

where size is total number of actual page.

Comment: I'm curious where you're getting size from? I cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: Oh I see. That's just an int. Let me try.

Comment: Worked great. Thank you!